# In Pyspark, I have two dfs with lists of events. Each event in the second df has a "duration". How do I sum the durations between events?

Tags: pandas, pyspark

Let's say the two dataframes look a bit like this:

| event | datetime | prev_datetime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| First | 10:54 AM, 11/3/21 | null |
| Second | 3:22 PM, 11/6/21 | 10:54 AM, 11/3/21 |
| Third | 11:01 AM, 11/8/21 | 3:22 PM, 11/6/21 |

| event | datetime | duration |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2 AM, 11/1/21 | 30 |
| B | 3 AM, 11/4/21 | 40 |
| C | 3 AM, 11/5/21 | 20 |
| D | 4 AM, 11/9/21 | 70 |

I would like to create a column in the first dataframe that would sum the duration of all the events in the second dataframe that take place between that and the previous event. (So in this case, it would be "60" for the second event.)

(The actual DFs use proper Unix timestamps.)

I've tried a merge and then groupby (too slow - working with very large datasets.) I've tried code like this that doesn't seem to work:

`df1 = df1.withColumn("time_between",F.sum(F.when((df2["datetime"] > df1["datetime"])&(df2["datetime"] < df1["prev_datetime"]),df2["duration"])))`

Is there a correct fast way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the solution consists of following steps

First convert the time strings to their timestamp counterparts.

Then do a clever join of the two dataframes keeping your join condition in mind.

Finally do a groupby to sum the duration column.

```
from pyspark import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

sc = SparkContext('local')
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

### This is very important setting if you want legacy behaviour
sqlContext.setConf("spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy", "LEGACY")


data1 = [
["First",  "10:54 AM, 11/3/21",   "null"],
["Second",  "3:22 PM, 11/6/21",   "10:54 AM, 11/3/21"],
["Third",   "11:01 AM, 11/8/21",  "3:22 PM, 11/6/21"]
]
columns1 =["df1_event", "df1_datetime",  "df1_prev_datetime"]

df1 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(data=data1, schema=columns1)
df1 = df1.withColumn("df1_datetime", to_timestamp(F.col("df1_datetime"), "KK:mm a, MM/dd/yy"))
df1 = df1.withColumn("df1_prev_datetime", to_timestamp(F.col("df1_prev_datetime"), "KK:mm a, MM/dd/yy"))

print("First dataframe")
df1.show(n=10, truncate=False)

print("schema of df1")
print(df1.schema)



data2 = [
["A",   "2 AM, 11/1/21",   30],
["B",   "3 AM, 11/4/21",   40],
["C",   "3 AM, 11/5/21",   20],
["D",   "4 AM, 11/9/21",   70],
]
columns2 =["df2_event",   "df2_datetime",    "df2_duration"]


df2 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(data=data2, schema=columns2)
df2 = df2.withColumn("df2_datetime", to_timestamp(F.col("df2_datetime"), "KK a, MM/dd/yy"))
print("Second dataframe")
df2.show(n=10, truncate=False)

print("schema of df2")
print(df2.schema)


result = df1.join(df2, (F.col("df2_datetime") >= F.col("df1_prev_datetime")) & (F.col("df2_datetime") <= F.col("df1_datetime"))) \
           .groupBy(F.col("df1_event")) \
           .agg(F.sum(F.col("df2_duration"))).withColumnRenamed("sum(df2_duration)", "total_duration")


result.show()
```

Output :

```
First dataframe
+---------+-------------------+-------------------+
|df1_event|df1_datetime       |df1_prev_datetime  |
+---------+-------------------+-------------------+
|First    |2021-11-03 10:54:00|null               |
|Second   |2021-11-06 15:22:00|2021-11-03 10:54:00|
|Third    |2021-11-08 11:01:00|2021-11-06 15:22:00|
+---------+-------------------+-------------------+

schema of df1
StructType([StructField('df1_event', StringType(), True), StructField('df1_datetime', TimestampType(), True), StructField('df1_prev_datetime', TimestampType(), True)])
Second dataframe
+---------+-------------------+------------+
|df2_event|df2_datetime       |df2_duration|
+---------+-------------------+------------+
|A        |2021-11-01 02:00:00|30          |
|B        |2021-11-04 03:00:00|40          |
|C        |2021-11-05 03:00:00|20          |
|D        |2021-11-09 04:00:00|70          |
+---------+-------------------+------------+

schema of df2
StructType([StructField('df2_event', StringType(), True), StructField('df2_datetime', TimestampType(), True), StructField('df2_duration', LongType(), True)])
+---------+--------------+
|df1_event|total_duration|
+---------+--------------+
|   Second|            60|
+---------+--------------+
```